# Django API REST : Issue with function in CreateAPIView

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm working on my `Django API Rest` but it's pretty new for me and I have one more question about my code.

I'm reading all the time [Django Rest Doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/)

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**FIRST PART - My code :**

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

I have a **serializer.py** file which describe my `ModelSerializer` like this :

```
class IndividuCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer) :
    class Meta :
        model = Individu
        fields = [
            'Etat',
            'Civilite',
            'Nom',
            'Prenom',
            'Sexe',
            'Statut',
            'DateNaissance',
            'VilleNaissance',
            'PaysNaissance',
            'Nationalite1',
            'Nationalite2',
            'Profession',
            'Adresse',
            'Ville',
            'Zip',
            'Pays',
            'Mail',
            'Telephone',
            'Image',
            'CarteIdentite',
            ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
       print('toto')
       obj = Individu.objects.create(**validated_data)
       Identity_Individu_Resume(self.context.get('request'), obj.id)
       return obj
```

This create function calls another function which is not in my API module, but in my main module : `Identity_Individu_Resume`

As you can see here, this function takes the last created object and applies multiple processes :

```
@login_required
def Identity_Individu_Resume(request, id) :

    personne = get_object_or_404(Individu, pk=id)

    NIU = lib.Individu_Recherche.NIUGeneratorIndividu(personne)
    personne.NumeroIdentification = NIU

    if personne.Image != " " :
        NewImageName = 'pictures/' + personne.Nom +'_'+ personne.Prenom +'_'+  NIU + '.jpg'
        FilePath = settings.MEDIA_ROOT 
        FilePathOLD = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + str(personne.Image)
        FilePathNEW = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + NewImageName

        file = os.path.exists(FilePath)
        if file :
            os.rename(FilePathOLD, FilePathNEW)

        personne.Image = NewImageName

    if personne.CarteIdentite != " " :
        NewCarteName = 'Carte_Identite/' + 'Carte_Identite_' + personne.Nom +'_'+ personne.Prenom +'_'+  NIU + '.jpg'
        FilePath = settings.MEDIA_ROOT 
        FilePathOLD = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + str(personne.CarteIdentite)
        FilePathNEW = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + NewCarteName

        file = os.path.exists(FilePath)
        if file :
            os.rename(FilePathOLD, FilePathNEW)

        personne.CarteIdentite = NewCarteName

    else :
        pass

    personne.save()

    context = {
                "personne" : personne,
                "NIU" : NIU,
    }

    return render(request, 'Identity_Individu_Resume.html', context)
```

Then, I have in my API module a **views.py** file with a specific class named `IndividuCreateAPIView` which is very simple and call my serializer class describes above :

```
class IndividuCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView) :
    queryset = Individu.objects.all()
    serializer_class = IndividuCreateSerializer
```

Then I have my **urls.py** file :

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', IndividuListAPIView.as_view() , name="IndividuList"),
    url(r'^docs/', schema_view),
    url(r'^create/$', IndividuCreateAPIView.as_view() , name="Create"),
]
```

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**SECOND PART - Using API REST Interface :**

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

In this part, I'm using my API Rest interface with `http://localhost:8000/Api/Identification/`

[image]

When I create an object, the `create function` in my serializers.py file works well and I get a well-created object in my database :

[image]

So there is none issue !

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**THIRD PART - Using API REST with pythonic file :**

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

In this case, I'm getting an issue.

I have a file `API_create.py` which is executed from my terminal and should simulate an external application which try to connect to my API and create an object.

import requests

```
url = 'http://localhost:8000/Api/Identification/create/'

filename1 = '/Users/valentin/Desktop/Django/DatasystemsCORE/Media/pictures/photo.jpg'
filename2 = '/Users/valentin/Desktop/Django/DatasystemsCORE/Media/Carte_Identite/carte_ID.gif'
files = {'Image' : open(filename1,'rb'), 'CarteIdentite': open(filename2,'rb')}

data = {
    "Etat": "Vivant",
    "Civilite": "Monsieur",
    "Nom": "creation",
    "Prenom": "via-api",
    "Sexe": "Masculin",
    "Statut": "Célibataire",
    "DateNaissance": "1991-11-23",
    "VilleNaissance": "STRASBOURG",
    "PaysNaissance": "FR",
    "Nationalite1": "FRANCAISE",
    "Nationalite2": "",
    "Profession": "JJJ",
    "Adresse": "12, rue des fleurs",
    "Ville": "STRASBOURG",
    "Zip": 67000,
    "Pays": "FR",
    "Mail": "",
    "Telephone": ""
    }

response = requests.post(url, files=files, data=data)

print(response.text)
```

But, when I execute this script, my object is well-created BUT the function `create` in my serializers.py is not called !

In this case, I'm getting that :

[image]

My question is : Why my create function doesn't work ? I don't understand because my url is correct and should call this function in order to replace my NIU (NULL) by the generated NIU and change pictures names too ...

Could you help me to find why it doesn't work ?

Comment: Probably this is because of `login_required` decorator in `Identity_Individu_Resume` view. You can try to remove it or you need to provide auth token with request: `response = requests.post(url, files=files, data=data, headers={'Authorization': 'Token <MY_TOKEN>'})`.

Comment: @neverwalkaloner I love you ! 2 days on this issue .. I comment it and it works !
So I have to look further on auth token. It's totally new. Post your answer and I will accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this is because of `login_required` decorator in `Identity_Individu_Resume` view. You can try to remove it or you need to provide auth token with request: `response = requests.post(url, files=files, data=data, headers={'Authorization': 'Token <MY_TOKEN>'})`.

**UPD**

Actually I suppose it would be better to move common part of api and non-api views to third function and call it separately from both views. In this case you probaly would like to add `login_required` to `IndividuCreateAPIView` view also. In this case you need to add `IsAuthenticated` permission like this:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
class IndividuCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView) :
    queryset = Individu.objects.all()
    serializer_class = IndividuCreateSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

Comment: Thank you @neverwalkaloner ! If I want to replace `MY_TOKEN`, I have to pick up token somewhere or create a new one ?

Comment: @Deadpool you need to add `TokenAuthentication` to your project. Check details here http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#authentication

Comment: @Deadpool actually it looks a little weird to call non api view from api view. I suggest you to move common part of this views to third function and call it separately from both views. In this case you probaly would like to add `login_required` to api view also. In this case you need to add `IsAuthenticated` permission class to `IndividuCreateAPIView`.

Comment: Ok, but I have to generate token auth right ? If I understand, I move common part (i.e all content) in a third function and I can write `login_required` into my non-api view and call function into my api without `login-required` ?

Comment: @Deadpool correct, if you move logic into non-view function. You can call this function from serializer and in this case you dont need token.